# Repeat mp3 file on click for selective time Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, loops, avaudioplayer

i want to repeat mp3 file for selective times in Xcode Swift, how can i add button that will pop up on click that shows repeat numbers like 11,21,51,108

and when user click on number 11 the mp3 file should play for 11 times currently i am using 108 times for default but i want that user can customise it..

this is my code for play

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if player.isPlaying {

            player.stop()
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"play.png"),for: .normal)
        } else {
            player.play()
            player.numberOfLoops = 108
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"pause.png"),for: .normal)
        }


    }
```

Comment: What is a “button that will pop up on click”?

Answer (score 0):

You can create 5 UIButtons with IBAction for each button.

- If user pressed 1st button -> number of loops will be 11
- If user pressed 2nd button -> number of loops will be 21
- same for other buttons

You need to create a button for each loops variation.

Or you can create, for example, PickerView, get value of loops from there and pass this value into function.